# SYSVOL replication issue

Tags: replication, dfs-replication

I have 2 DC's on windows server 2019 that have a replication issue with the sysvol folder that it's not replicated when I try create a folder on DC1 isn't not replicated on DC2. I tried repadmin commands in [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/identity/replication-error-1722-rpc-server-unavailable) and there's no error shown.

I found logs for DFSR: event ID 4612,5008,5002